# generate serial number in decreasing order given a variable in netezza aginity sql

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

Is there any SQL syntax using netezza SQL, given column number, trying to generate rows for number in decreasing order down to 0.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do

BEFORE

| ID | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |

AFTER

| ID | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 1 |

please also click to see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFKY7.png) for example thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `_v_vector_idx` table for this purpose

```sql
select 
  id, idx 
from 
  test join _v_vector_idx 
     on idx <= number
order
  by id asc, idx desc ;
```

Here's the example in action

```
select * from test
  ID   | NUMBER
-------+--------
 A     |      4
 B     |      5
(2 rows)


select id, idx from test join _v_vector_idx on
   idx <= number order by id asc, idx desc ;
  ID   | IDX
-------+-----
 A     |   4
 A     |   3
 A     |   2
 A     |   1
 A     |   0
 B     |   5
 B     |   4
 B     |   3
 B     |   2
 B     |   1
 B     |   0
(11 rows)

insert into test values ('C', 3);
INSERT 0 1

select * from test;
  ID   | NUMBER
-------+--------
 A     |      4
 B     |      5
 C     |      3
(3 rows)

select id, idx from test join _v_vector_idx
  on idx <= number order by id asc, idx desc ;
  ID   | IDX
-------+-----
 A     |   4
 A     |   3
 A     |   2
 A     |   1
 A     |   0
 B     |   5
 B     |   4
 B     |   3
 B     |   2
 B     |   1
 B     |   0
 C     |   3
 C     |   2
 C     |   1
 C     |   0
(15 rows)
```

Comment: @user15957051 . . . This is a good answer but be warned that `_v_vector_idx` has 1,024 rows so it works so long as the maximum number is not greater than that.